# Existence of vector extensions for the Hessian

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Q: $p$ a critical point of a smooth $f$ and $v, w$ two vectors in $T_{p}M$. We extend these two to vector fields $v^{*}, w^{*}$ such that at $p$ the first one equals $v$ and the second one equals $w.$ Then the Hessian $d_{p}^{2}f(v,w) = L_{v^{*}}L_{w^{*}}f.$ NTS:
a) that $v^{*}, w^{*}$ exist and the Hessian is independent of this choice. Here i also need to state the importance of $p$ being a critical point.
b)Want to prove that the Hessian is greater or equal to 0 for all $v$ when $p$ is a local min of $f.$ And $p$ is a local min when the Hessian is greater or equal to $0$ for all non 0 $v.$

Comment: where are you stuck at?

Comment: I am stuck at part b, and also i can intuitively understand that p needs to be critical for Hessian to be well-defined, but how would you formalize this?